# System.out.println a fichero external storage

Tags: java, android-studio

necesito transformar la salida println en una variable para transformarla en un fichero.

Tengo por una parte el bucle y el println y por otra la parte que genera el fichero ( ahora está con otra variable, esto es para mejorar el proceso).

```
String[] items = codbarras.split("\n");
    for (String item : items)
    {
        String value = ("item = " +"T"+Origen_t+Destino_t+ String.format("%-25s",item)+"0000000001\n");
        System.out.println (value);//("item = " +"T"+Origen_t+Destino_t+ String.format("%-25s",item)+"0000000001");
    }
```

El resultado que obtengo en System.out.println es el quiero convertir en un fichero en ExternalStorageDirectory

Y esta es la parte que tengo para generar el fichero:

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());
    long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date curDateTime = new Date(msTime);
    // nombre fichero //
    String nombre="TRASPASO_"+Origen_T+"==>"+Destino_T+"__"+ curDateTime+".csv" ;

    try {
        File tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(this, tarjetaSD.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File rutaArchivo = new File(tarjetaSD.getPath(), nombre);
        OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo =new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo));
        //OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
        crearArchivo.write(saludo);
        crearArchivo.flush();
        crearArchivo.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        etOrigen.setText("");
        etNombre.setText("");
        etEdad.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Ahora el String que convierto en fichero es "saludo" , gracias de antemano

Comment: Y el problema que tienes es???

Comment: que por una parte tengo el resultado en el print , pero quiero que esté en la variable "saludo" para poder guardarla en el fichero, seguro que parezco tonto pero no veo como hacerlo

Comment: El problema es que como has subido partes del código separadas, no tengo información de dónde está cada parte en el programa global, así que no te puedo decir. No se dónde defines la variable `saludo` y si es visible en el sitio en el que generas la cadena. O si después de generar la cadena, dónde está definida la variable `saludo` para setearla. Tu problema entonces es de ámbito de las variables. Define la variable `saludo` en algún sitio que sea visible en ambos sitios. En uno la seteas y en otro la escribes en el fichero.

Comment: Vale ahora lo subo entero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale. Aclarado el tema, podrías hacer algo así, obviando el resto del código hasta llegar al for:

```
String CadenaFinal = "";
for (String item : items)
{
    CadenaFinal += ("item = " +"T"+Origen_t+Destino_t+ String.format("%-25s",item)+"0000000001\n");

}

//////////////////////////////////////

// variable que utilizo actualmente //
String saludo = CadenaFinal; //O directamente usar CadenaFinal y eliminar saludo.
```

Comment: Fantástico, muchas gracias; solo como curiosidad, como de complejo sería enviar ese fichero por correo electrónico , me refiero crearlo y enviarlo al mismo tiempo, ( siempre al mismo correo)

Comment: Te recomiendo que crees otra pregunta para lo del envío por correo. Sino, salvo que alguien se lea los comentarios no se va a enterar de tu necesidad y no podrá ayudarte.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón , gracias

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código entero

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et_nombre;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    ///Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.letra,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    // Declaracion variable local para texview
   /* TextView tvSaludar = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvSaludo );
    String saludo = getString(R.string.letra );
    tvSaludar.setText(saludo);*/

    EditText etTexto = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.etOrigen );
    EditText etTexto2 = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.etDestino );
    //etTexto.setText("Hola que tal estás");
    //etTexto.setText(R.string.letra);



}
public void btnSaludar_Click(View view){
    //Acceso a Tienda origen
    EditText etOrigen =(EditText)findViewById( R.id.etOrigen );
    //Acceso a Tienda destino
    EditText etNombre =(EditText)findViewById( R.id.etDestino );
    //Acceso edad
    EditText etEdad =(EditText)findViewById( R.id.etEdad );
    //TextView tvSaludar = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tvSaludo );
    // variable solo texto
    String solotexto=etNombre.getText().toString(); // string del nombre tienda origen
    int Destino_T = Integer.parseInt(solotexto);
    String Destino_t =String.format("%6d", Destino_T);
    String strorigen=etOrigen.getText().toString(); // string del nombre tienda origen
    int Origen_T = Integer.parseInt(strorigen);
    String Origen_t =String.format("%6d", Origen_T);
    String letra_t = getString(R.string.letra );
    String unidad_f = "0000000001";
    String codbarras = etEdad.getText().toString(); // string de edad que es codbarras



    String cadena = codbarras;
    int contador = 0;
    int indice = cadena.indexOf("\n");
    while (indice >= 0) {
        contador++;
        indice = cadena.indexOf("\n", indice + 1);
    }
            ////////////
        //////////  variable que deseo crear y utilizar ////////
    String[] items = codbarras.split("\n");
    for (String item : items)
    {
        String value = ("item = " +"T"+Origen_t+Destino_t+ String.format("%-25s",item)+"0000000001\n");
        System.out.println (value);//("item = " +"T"+Origen_t+Destino_t+ String.format("%-25s",item)+"0000000001");
    }

        //////////////////////////////////////

    // variable que utilizo actualmente //
    String saludo = letra_t +Origen_t +Destino_t + codbarras_1;
    saludo = saludo.replace("\n","\n"+"T"+Origen_t +Destino_t);
    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,saludo,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    saludo = saludo.substring(0, saludo.length()-13);  // borro la  última línea

    // fecha y hora fichero //
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());
    long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date curDateTime = new Date(msTime);
    // nombre fichero //
    String nombre="TRASPASO_"+Origen_T+"==>"+Destino_T+"__"+ curDateTime+".csv" ;

    try {
        File tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(this, tarjetaSD.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File rutaArchivo = new File(tarjetaSD.getPath(), nombre);
        OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo =new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo));
        //OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
        crearArchivo.write(saludo);
        crearArchivo.flush();
        crearArchivo.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        etOrigen.setText("");
        etNombre.setText("");
        etEdad.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Pero en el `for` vas creando una cadena `value` en cada iteración, y no me queda claro si al final `saludo` tiene que tener el contenido de todas las iteraciones. Si es así, puedes definir una variable `String` fuera del `for` y en cada iteración del `for`, le añades a lo que ya tenías de las iteraciones anteriores, el contenido de `value`. Al terminar el `for` tendrás todos los mensajes y podrás asignarselos a la variable saludo, o incluso que la variable que defines fuera del `for` sea directamente `saludo`.

Comment: Justo es eso lo que no me sale, o no se plantearlo de manera correcta, quiero que el contenido de "value" (completo ) esté dentro de "saludo" u otra variable me da igual